# How to create a local DNS server to hand queries from different local servers

Tags: networking, server, dns, bind

I have 3 DNS servers  , a Master server ( which maps names to IPs and vice versa in my LAN) as well as a slave DNS server and a  caching server. Now I was hoping for some advice to create ONE server that can make where a client would use it as its DNS server and have access to the 3 DNS servers I made , I did some research online and this could be called a recursive name server or Root name server but I have found zero resources on how to do this using bind9

Comment: Are you talking of your home network? Whats the point of having more than 1-2 DNS-Servers there? Please explain more detailed, what you have and what you want - Perhaps a picture/drawing could help